# Custom button in django admin panel

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add a custom button in admin panel? To be more specific: I have a django app with some custom admin views, but without models. Now I can reach this app typing url. Maybe there is more appropriate way?

The difficulty is that I don't want to interract with the project, just with reusable app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the /admin/base_site.html template in your project by including a template with the same relative path on your projects /template dir.

Comment: I don't want to change project in any way, just my app. So if user download and install my app he not have to change anything in his project

Comment: You can do the same thing in your app and it'll work as long as the app comes after the admin in INSTALLED_APPS